# How to scrape the web table with multiple pages using R or Python

Tags: python, r, web, scrape

I want to scrape a web to gather the data for studying data mining. This web data contains a big table with 43 pages. And it also hide some stocks at the most right hand side of the expand menu.

[image]

The web page is below.

http://data.10jqka.com.cn/market/longhu/yyb/

```
import bs4
import requests


url = r"http://data.10jqka.com.cn/market/longhu/yyb/"

response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code == 200:
    content = response.content

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content)
table_results = soup.findAll("table", {"class": "m_table"})
for item in table_results:
    company_name = item.findAll("td", {"class": "tl"})[0].text.strip()
    detail = item.findAll("td", {"class": "tc"})[0].text.strip()
    c_rise = item.findAll("td", {"class": "c_rise"})[0].text.strip()
    c_fall = item.findAll("td", {"class": "c_fall"})[0].text.strip()
    cur = item.findAll("td", {"class": "cur"})[0].text.strip()
    lhb_stocklist = item.findAll("div", {"class": "lhb_stocklist"})[0].text.strip()
    print company_name, detail, c_rise, c_fall, lhb_stocklist
```

Comment: Right now what have you done? Any code?

Comment: @yan9yu, I tried R with XML and Curl. Rcause I am stronger in R than Python. But I still don't know how to scrape this table. I will update my code at the same time you try.

Comment: @yan9yu,hi, can you give me a hand,thanks!

Comment: You just want data on the first page, or all pages? Only "当日", or both "当日" and "当月"? The data on non-first pages are loaded through ajax

Comment: @ZZY, I want the data with "当月", and with all the 43 pages data. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution based on [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/#install), [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup), and [lxml](http://lxml.de/installation.html):

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'http://data.10jqka.com.cn/interface/market/longhuyyb/stocknum/desc/%d/20'
# config end_page as needed, or parse http://data.10jqka.com.cn/market/longhu/yyb/ to make it auto adapted
end_page = 2

result = []
for page_idx in range(1, end_page + 1):
    print 'Extracting page', page_idx
    raw_response = requests.get(URL % page_idx)
    page_content = json.loads(raw_response.text)['data']
    html = BeautifulSoup(page_content, 'lxml')
    for row in html.tbody.find_all('tr'):
        company = row.find(class_='tl').text
        detail_link = row.find(class_='tl').a['href']
        buy = float(row.find(class_='c_rise').text)
        sell = float(row.find(class_='c_fall').text)
        stock_cnt = int(row.find(class_='cur').text)
        stocks = []
        for a in row.find(class_='lhb_stocklist_box hide').p.find_all('a'):
            stocks.append((a.text, a['href']))
        result.append({
            'company': company,
            'detail_link': detail_link,
            'buy': buy,
            'sell': sell,
            'stock_cnt': stock_cnt,
            'stocks': stocks,
        })

print 'Company number:', len(result)
```

I put all data into a list of dictionaries, for easy accessing. You can modify the codes to directly write to a CSV or whatever

Comment: ， I just updated my code above. I run your code, and your code is not exactly I want except that the use of "当月". Can you run my code so you can understand what I want. Thanks!

Comment: As I saw, the difference is you're using " http://data.10jqka.com.cn/market/longhu/yyb/ ". That URL can only give you records on the first page, isn't it? So you already solved your issue?

Comment: almost, I mean, can you add the code to write.to csv to desktop?

Comment: You can refer to the example at https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer